# Composition and division notation for functions

Tags: calculus, functions, notation

To provide context:

In Spivak's *Calculus*, Chapter 10's Problem 19a reads as follows:

> If $f$ is three times differentiable and $f'(x)\neq 0$, the *Schwarzian derivative* of $f$ at $x$ is defined to be $$\mathscr Df(x)=\frac{f'''(x)}{f'(x)}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}\right)^2$$ Show that $\mathscr D(f\circ g)=[\mathscr Df\circ g]\cdot g'^{\ 2}+\mathscr Dg$

The final portion of the solution (provided by an official answer book) reads as follows:

\begin{align}
\cdots &= \frac{(f''' \circ g)g'^{\ 2}}{f'\circ g}+ \frac{3(f'' \circ g)g''}{f'\circ g}+ \frac{g'''}{g'}- \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{(f'' \circ g)\cdot g'}{f' \circ g}\right)^2-3 \frac{(f''\circ g)g''}{f' \circ g}- \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{g''}{g'}\right) \\
&=\left[\frac{f'''}{f'}\circ g - \frac{3}{2}\frac{f'' \circ g}{f' \circ g} \right]\cdot g'^{\ 2}+\frac{g'''}{g'} - \frac{3}{2}\left (\frac{g''}{g'}\right)^2
\end{align}

My question in particular is about the author's choice to express the fractions $\frac{f'''}{f'}\circ g$ and $- \frac{3}{2}\frac{f'' \circ g}{f' \circ g}$ in the depicted manner.

I'm not overly familiar with this style of abridged notation, but, generally speaking, I think I can infer their meaning.

Is it safe to assume that $\frac{f'''}{f'}\circ g$ is semantically equivalent to the expression $\frac{f''' \circ g}{f' \circ g}$? In which case, $-\frac{3}{2}\frac{f'' \circ g}{f' \circ g}$ is semantically equivalent to $-\frac{3}{2}\frac{f''}{f'}\circ g$?

If this is true, can I chop up the author's choice to express these terms differently (i.e. one is in a form where "$\circ g$" is not included in the fraction whereas in the other form, "$\circ g$" *is* included in the fraction) as *unintentional* (due to its irrelevance)?

**Edit**: I realized there is a typo in Spivak's solution. Specifically, the $-\frac{3}{2}\frac{f'' \circ g}{f' \circ g}$ should actually be:

$$-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f'' \circ g}{f' \circ g}\right)^2$$

The original question still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, given two functions $f,g:A\to\Bbb{R}$ where $A$ is any set, the notation $fg$ means the function $A\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for every $x\in A$, $(fg)(x):= f(x)\cdot g(x)$. So, we are defining the symbol $fg$ to be a function which is defined by pointwise multiplication.

Similarly, if $f,g:A\to\Bbb{R}$ are functions and $g$ is nowhere vanishing (i.e for each $x\in A$, $g(x)\neq 0$), then we can define the quotient function $\frac{f}{g}:A\to\Bbb{R}$ as for each $x\in A$, $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x):=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Once again, the quotient is defined pointwise.

Also, given a real number $c\in\Bbb{R}$ and a function $f:A\to\Bbb{R}$, by the symbol $cf$ one means the function $A\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for each $x\in A$, $(cf)(x):= c\cdot f(x)$.

Finally, for composition, assuming $A:A\to B$ and $f:B\to C$ are functions, by the symbol $f\circ g$, we mean the function $A\to C$ such that for each $x\in A$, $(f\circ g)(a):=f(g(a))$.

Now, a-priori, we should always use brackets to denote what we mean, so a-priori, the following could all mean different things

- $\left[-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''}{f'}\right)\right]\circ g$
- $-\frac{3}{2}\left[\left(\frac{f''}{f'}\right)\circ g\right]$
- $-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''\circ g}{f'\circ g}\right)$

But, a moment's consideration with the above definitions will show that these are all the same function, because for each $x\in\text{domain}(g)$, the value of these functions at the point $x$ is simply the real number
\begin{align}
-\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{f''(g(x))}{f'(g(x))}.
\end{align}
With some practice with the definitions, one gets comfortable with manipulating functions as easily as one manipulates real numbers, so it becomes immediately apparent that all these things are equal.

---

In the last equality, you write
\begin{align}
\cdots
&=\left[\frac{f'''}{f'}\circ g - \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f'' \circ g}{f' \circ g}\right)^2 \right]\cdot g'^{\ 2}+\frac{g'''}{g'} - \frac{3}{2}\left (\frac{g''}{g'}\right)^2
\end{align}
To really complete the proof, I would "simplify" it as follows
\begin{align}
\cdots &=\left[\frac{f'''}{f'}\circ g - \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''}{f'} \right)^2\circ g\right]\cdot g'^{\ 2}+\left[\frac{g'''}{g'} - \frac{3}{2}\left (\frac{g''}{g'}\right)^2\right]\\
&= \left(\left[\frac{f'''}{f'} - \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''}{f'} \right)^2\right]\circ g \right)\cdot g'^{\ 2}+\left[\frac{g'''}{g'} - \frac{3}{2}\left (\frac{g''}{g'}\right)^2\right]\\
&= \left([\mathcal{D} f]\circ g\right)\cdot (g')^2 + \mathcal{D}g
\end{align}

As you can see, in the first few steps of applying the chain rule, it is convenient to keep the composition with $g$ in the fractions itself, but towards the end of the solution, when you want to re-condense everything in terms of the Schwarzian derivative, it is convenient to pull the $\circ g$ out, so that we can write it correctly as $(\mathcal{D}f)\circ g$.

Comment: Perfectly thorough. Cheers!

Comment: One point of clarification, if you're willing. Using $(f'' \circ g)^2$ as an example, I would expand accordingly: $(f'' \circ g)^2(x)=f''(g(x)) \cdot f''(g(x)) = (f'' \cdot f'')(g(x))$. I take it as we are defining $(f'' \cdot f'')$ to be $f''^{\ 2}$?

Comment: @S.Cramer yes that's right. Generally, $(f\cdot g)\circ h = (f\circ h)\cdot (g\circ h)$ (can you see how from this you can deduce $(f''\circ g)^2= [(f'')^2]\circ g$?)